# How to activate all pages (tabs) concurrently in puppeteersharp

Tags: .net-5, puppeteer-sharp

I'm launching multiple tabs concurrently using puppeteersharp like so:

```
private async Task LaunchPages()
{
    var taskList = new List<Task>
    {
        LaunchPage("https://www.my-page.com"),
        LaunchPage("https://www.my-page2.com"),
        LaunchPage("https://www.my-page3.com")
    };
    
    await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
}

private async Task LaunchPage(string url)
{
    var page = await Browser.NewPageAsync();
    await page.GoToAsync(url, WaitUntilNavigation.DOMContentLoaded);
}
```

This launches all of the pages (tabs) properly, but only the last tab that was launched gets focus / brought to the front. As a result, the pages don't render and javascript doesn't run until physically clicking on the tab in the browser or calling `page.BringToFrontAsync()`. This seems to be the case even when the browser is in headless mode.

In my use case, calling `page.BringToFrontAsync()` before interacting with the page hasn't been working well due to completely separate tasks "fighting" over which tab is selected.

Is there a way to have all tabs do full rendering and javascript processing even if they haven't been focused?

Comment: You won't be able to work around that. But, PlaywrightSharp has that solved (technically there is no background page) so it could work for your use case.

Comment: @hardkoded Thanks, I'll give that a look. Puppeteersharp is great by the way